# Adding Spring for Android into Android Studio project

Tags: android, spring, android-studio

I'm trying my hand at android development for the first time, and I'd like to create an app, "MyFirstApp", that's going to make calls to REST services. I did a little research and it looks like Spring for Android is a good tool to help me with this. I've never used Spring, and I'm not very familiar with Android Studio yet, so I'm confused how I should add the dependencies for Spring into my project.

Spring's website has a piece of code they say to copy and paste into my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

I realize there's already a question posted that addresses a very similar issue, but I need help knowing EXACTLY which file to add the above code to, and EXACTLY where to do so.

I have two "build.gradle" files that were created in my project. First is

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.owner.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Second is build.gradle(Project: MyFirstApp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    }repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can anyone help show me where in these two files I should include the Spring dependency? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `build.gradle (Module: app)` inside `dependencies`

```
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
```

Add this in `build.gradle(Project: MyFirstApp)` inside `repositories`

```
maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
```

That's it. You are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are behind a firewall, so this should really be a suggestion, but need to show formatted code:
Try replacing https with http here:

```
maven {
    url 'http**s**://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
}
```

And add a url for jcenter:

```
 repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the `compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'` under the dependencies in `build.gradle(Module:app)` and then the maven block:

```
maven {
    url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
}
```

Is put in the allprojects set of braces below the dependencies block.